# Prevent Shutdown/Sleep on Macs

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to be able to implement methods to prevent these from happening:

- Shutdown
- Restart
- Logoff
- Sleep

On a Mac, I am using Xcode but can't seem to figure out the code to perform these actions.

Can anyone help me out here?

I found this : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1134/_index.html

but I can't seem to understand how to block the system events when they are triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Carbon's [Application Manager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Dock_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SetSystemUIMode), there's the `SetSystemUIMode` API which lets you control (disable) things like force-quit, the power-key window etc. It's intended for kiosk style applications and described in [this tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html).

Disabling sleep, screen-saver, etc. is done by periodically calling `UpdateSystemActivity`. See [this tech Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1160/_index.html).

Comment: `UpdateSystemActivity` is deprecated as of 10.8.  The header comments say to use `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and most effective way to prevent Apple OSX to sleep is the Terminal command:

```
   $ pmset noidle
   Preventing idle sleep (^C to exit)...
```

The only annoying thing maybe the user self has to end this manually by issuing a 'Control-C'.